# Pass parameters to query with spark.read.format(jdbc) format

Tags: sql, pyspark, jdbc, amazon-redshift

I am trying to execute following sample query throug spark.read.format("jdbc") in redshift

```
query="select * from tableA join tableB on a.id = b.id where a.date > ? and b.date > ?"
```

I am trying to execute this query as follows:

> I read query_parameters from a table and I am getting a dataframe and then made it as a list by using df.collect() statement and then converting to tuple to pass it as parameters

```
query_parameters = ("2022-01-01","2023-01-01")

df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", url) \
  .option("query",query) \
  .option("user","user") \
  .option("password", pass) \
  .option("queryParameters", ",".join(query_parameters)) \
  .option("driver", driver) \
  .load()
```

I am getting following error:

```
com.amazon.redshift.util.RedshiftException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: \"?\"\r\n\tat
```

How do we pass parameters to the query when we are executing through spark.read in pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official [spark-redshift](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) implementation, it seems that there is no option named *queryParameters* available. Not sure where you found it, but I wasn't able to find it in the official github [code](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift).

The only way to pass parameters to your query is through Python string concatenation or interpolation and setting the `query` option of the driver, as shown in the corresponding test suite [RedshiftReadSuite.scala](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/blob/184b4428c1505dff7b4365963dc344197a92baa9/src/it/scala/com/databricks/spark/redshift/RedshiftReadSuite.scala#L99).

For the above example this should work:

```py
query_parameters = ("2022-01-01","2023-01-01")

query=f"select * from tableA join tableB on a.id = b.id where a.date > '{query_parameters[0]}'' and b.date > '{query_parameters[1]}'"

df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", url) \
  .option("query",query) \
  .option("user","user") \
  .option("password", pass) \
  .option("driver", driver) \
  .load()
```